# CAML Query is not filtering anything when using a Person or Group type column

Tags: caml-query, spservices

I'm trying to get a list count based on the CAML query below, but it keeps returning zero. It should return the number of projects assigned to a designer (**person or group type column**) which their project status is NOT complete. Any ideas what might have wrong in my code.

**Here are some excerpts of my code:**

```
<!-- SPSERVICE QUERY BLOCK-->
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".showResultsOpenProjs").click(function(){
        var selectedDesignerOpenProjs = $("#selectedDesignerOpenProjs").val(); alert(selectedDesignerOpenProjs);

        $().SPServices({

operation: "GetListItems",
async: false,
listName: "Marketing Requests",
CAMLRowLimit: 5000,
CAMLQuery: "<Query><Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='Assign_x0020_To'/><Value Type='User' >" + selectedDesignerOpenProjs + "</Value></Eq><And><Neq><FieldRef Name='Status'/><Value Type='Text' >COMPLETED</Value></Neq><Neq><FieldRef Name='Status'/><Value Type='Text' >CANCELLED</Value></Neq></And></And></Where></Query>",


            completefunc: function(xData, Status)
            {
                var dataLengthOpenProjs = $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").length;
                $(".resultsDivOpenProjs").html("Designer: <b>" + selectedDesignerOpenProjs + " </b><br>Projects in this date range: <br><h1><b>" + dataLengthOpenProjs + "</b></h1>");
                $(".resultsDiv2").empty();

                $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function()
                {
                    var jobIDOpenProjs = parseInt($(this).attr("ows_ID"));
                    console.log($(this).attr("ows_Title"));

                    $(".resultsDiv2").append("Project Title: <b>" + jobIDOpenProjs + " - <a href='https://dschs.sharepoint.com/SchoolDevelopment/StudentOutreach/Lists/Marketing%20Requests/Item/displayifs.aspx?List=f13e5db4-080c-4be2-92e9-7df0b7cdd852&ID=" + jobIDOpenProjs + "' target='_blank'>"+$(this).attr("ows_Title")+"</a></b><br>");
                });



    /************Debugging********
        alert(Status);
        var out = $().SPServices.SPDebugXMLHttpResult({
        node: xData.responseXML
        });
        $("#debug").html("").append("<b>This is the output from the GetList operation:</b>" + out);
    /******************************/


            }
        });
    })
});         
</script>
```

Comment: Is your `Assign To` field a person type field?  What's an example value for `selectedDesignerOpenProjs`?

Comment: Your `<And>` tags aren't nested properly, plus you have `<And></And>` towards the end of your query string that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @ErinL yes. "Assign To" column is a Person/Group people picker column.

Comment: @ErinL I tried the CAML query you provided and still returns 0. I already have a view for this list displaying only NOT COMPLETE projects. I set the viewName to the name of this view, and still nothing. An example value you could use is "Jake White"

Comment: @ErinL when activating column totals, the count for "Jake White" comes to 23 open projects.

Comment: Since you're using name, not user ID, you can't use the lookup type. I'll edit my code.

Comment: @ErinL changing "lookup" to "user" and still nothing is being returned. Perhaps get rid of the viewName or edit the CAMLViewFields?

Comment: Did you also get rid of `LookupId='TRUE'`?

Comment: @ErinL yes, I did.

Comment: @ErinL also, I open the Chrome console and when running the block of code, I get a POST 500 internal error.

Comment: Try adding Status to your ViewFields

Comment: Do you get results if you remove the CAMLQuery?

Comment: @ErinL I already have "Status" in ViewFields. Everything runs fine once I remove the CAML Query. It displays all open projects regardless of assigned designer.

Comment: Status isn't listed above. Do you want to update your code here so that I can see all the changes you've made?

Comment: @ErinL Done. I have updated the code on my original post.

Comment: If your view contains all the fields you need, I'd remove the `CAMLViewFields` line. I'd also edit the view so that records are excluded if Status is null.  Then I'd focus on getting the CAMLQuery filter to work. The more we can simplify it, the easier it'll be to see our error.

Comment: @ErinL From the debug div:

This is the output from the GetList operation:
#document
soap:Envelope
0 xmlns:soap http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/
1 xmlns:xsi http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance
2 xmlns:xsd http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
soap:Body
soap:Fault
faultcode soap:Server
faultstring Exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException' was thrown.
detail
errorstring One or more field types are not installed properly. Go to the list settings page to delete these fields.
errorcode 0x81020014

Comment: If your view is set up that way, then remove the IsNotNull section from your query

Comment: I replaced my code below to the most simplified version I could.

Comment: @ErinL Thank you. I updated the CAML Query to the one you provided, and the count is now 421 for "Jake White" when it should be 23. *scratches head*

Comment: That's kind of fascinating... though I have no thoughts on why.  Is the count for Jake 421 if status isn't taken into account? Maybe the query is overriding the view.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42521/discussion-on-question-by-ivan-caml-query-is-not-filtering-anything-when-using-a).

Comment: @ErinL Hi Erin, I double checked the 'display names' for this two users, and they are in the same formats as everyone else. These two users have just a firstname and lastname. When I run the query, the script doesnt return any errors, but no results. At this point, do you think their display names should be readjusted in Central Administration to make sure they follow the same format as everyone else? I can't think of any other thing as why my script is not working with certain users.

Answer (score 3):

```
operation: "GetListItems",
async: false,
listName: "Marketing Requests",
viewName: "54E61A50-B5A9-4D59-91B9-EA9D280B8C24",
CAMLRowLimit: 5000,
CAMLQuery: "<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Assign_x0020_To'/><Value Type='User' >" + selectedDesignerOpenProjs + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query>",
completefunc: function(xData, Status){
        /************Debugging********/
            alert(Status);
            var out = $().SPServices.SPDebugXMLHttpResult({
            node: xData.responseXML
            });
            $("#debug").html("").append("<b>This is the output from the GetList operation:</b>" + out);
        /******************************/
}
```